# WordPress remove manual Ajax trigger and use infinite scroll

Tags: ajax, wordpress, jquery-isotope, infinite-scroll

I have a problem with my script.  I want to remove the `load more` button and instead do an infinite scroll when I get to bottom of the page.

I'm using a WordPress template and without support I'm stuck on this nonsense.

What should I change to do to this script?

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

    var $container = $('#hentry-wrapper');



    // Isotope

    // modified Isotope methods for gutters in masonry

    $.Isotope.prototype._getMasonryGutterColumns = function() {

        var gutter = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.gutterWidth || 0;

            containerWidth = this.element.width();



    this.masonry.columnWidth = this.options.masonry && this.options.masonry.columnWidth ||

              // or use the size of the first item

              this.$filteredAtoms.outerWidth(true) ||

              // if there's no items, use size of container

              containerWidth;



    this.masonry.columnWidth += gutter;



    this.masonry.cols = Math.floor( ( containerWidth + gutter ) / this.masonry.columnWidth );

    this.masonry.cols = Math.max( this.masonry.cols, 1 );

    };



    $.Isotope.prototype._masonryReset = function() {

        // layout-specific props

        this.masonry = {};

        // FIXME shouldn't have to call this again

        this._getMasonryGutterColumns();

        var i = this.masonry.cols;

        this.masonry.colYs = [];

        while (i--) {

            this.masonry.colYs.push( 0 );

        }

    };



    $.Isotope.prototype._masonryResizeChanged = function() {

        var prevSegments = this.masonry.cols;

        // update cols/rows

        this._getMasonryGutterColumns();

        // return if updated cols/rows is not equal to previous

        return ( this.masonry.cols !== prevSegments );

    };



    var loadMore = $('#load-more');

    var posts_per_page = parseInt(loadMore.attr('data-perpage'));

    var offset = posts_per_page;

    var totalPosts = parseInt(loadMore.attr('data-total-posts'));

    var author = parseInt(loadMore.attr('data-author'));

    var category = parseInt(loadMore.attr('data-category'));

    var tag = loadMore.attr('data-tag');

    var datemonth = loadMore.attr('data-month');

    var dateyear = loadMore.attr('data-year');

    var search = loadMore.attr('data-search');

    var loader = $('#posts-count').attr('data-loader');



    if (!author) author = 0;

    if (!category) category = 0;

    if (!tag) tag = '';

    if (!datemonth) datemonth = 0;

    if (!dateyear) dateyear = 0;

    if (!search) search = '';



    // cache jQuery window

    var $window = $(window);



    // start up isotope with default settings

    $(window).load(function(){

        reLayout();

        $window.smartresize( reLayout );

        if (offset < totalPosts) {

            $('#nav-pagination-load-more').fadeIn(200);

            mega_initLoadMore();

        }

    });



    function reLayout() {



        var mediaQueryId = getComputedStyle( document.body, ':after' ).getPropertyValue('content');

        // fix for firefox, remove double quotes "

        //mediaQueryId = mediaQueryId.replace( /"/g, '' );

        //console.log( mediaQueryId );

        var windowSize = $window.width();

        var masonryOpts;

        // update sizing options 

        switch ( mediaQueryId ) {

            case 'large' :

                masonryOpts = {

                  gutterWidth: 0

                };

            break;



            case 'big' :

                masonryOpts = {

                  //columnWidth: 297,

                  gutterWidth: 0

                };

            break;



            case 'medium' :

                masonryOpts = {

                  //columnWidth: 269,

                  gutterWidth: 0

                };

            break;



            case 'small' :

            masonryOpts = {

              //columnWidth: $container.width() / 4,

              gutterWidth: 0

            };

            break;



            case 'tiny' :

            masonryOpts = {

              //columnWidth: $container.width() / 1,

              gutterWidth: 0

            };

            break;

        }



        $container.isotope({

          resizable: false, // disable resizing by default, we'll trigger it manually

          itemSelector : '.type-post',

          transformsEnabled: false, // Firefox Vimeo issue

          masonry: masonryOpts

        }).isotope( 'reLayout' );



    }



    function mega_initLoadMore(){

        loadMore.click(function(e) {

            $(this).unbind("click").addClass('active'); 

            $('#posts-count').html('<img src="'+ loader +'"/>');    

            e.preventDefault();

            mega_loadMorePosts();

        });

    }



    function mega_reLayout(){

        $container.isotope( 'reLayout' );   

    }



    function mega_loadMorePosts(){

            jQuery.ajax({

                url: megaAjax.ajaxurl,

                type: 'POST',

                data: {

                    action : 'mega_ajax_blog',

                    nonce : megaAjax.nonce,

                    category: category,

                    author: author,

                    tag: tag,

                    datemonth: datemonth,

                    dateyear: dateyear,

                    search: search,

                    offset: offset

                },

                success: function( data ) {

                    var $newElems = $(data);

                    // ensure that images load before adding to masonry layout

                    $newElems.imagesLoaded( function(){

                        // FitVids

                        $('.fluid-video, .entry-content', $newElems).fitVids();



                        $container.append($newElems).isotope( 'appended', $newElems );



                        // Flex Slider

                        $('.flexslider', $newElems).flexslider({

                            animation: "fade",

                            slideshow: false,

                            keyboard: false,

                            directionNav: true,

                            touch: true,

                            prevText: "",

                            nextText: ""

                        });



                        setTimeout(function(){

                            mega_reLayout();

                        }, 1000);



                        offset = offset + posts_per_page;

                        loadMore.removeClass('active');

                        if (offset < totalPosts){

                            $('#posts-count').text('');

                            loadMore.bind("click", mega_initLoadMore());

                        }

                        else {

                            setTimeout(function(){

                                loadMore.parent().remove();

                            }, 1000 );  

                        }                           

                    });

                }

            });

        return false;

    }
```

});

Answer (score 0):

I think this script is taken from "HEAT WORDPRESS THEME" directly which is located in js folder of the theme. Its simple to modify,you just need to remove Ajax post loading function and keep Isotop initializing function only. For help see this link 
http://www.shambix.com/en/isotope-twitter-bootstrap-infinite-scroll-fluid-responsive-layout/